# Can JMeter master be used as a load generator?

Tags: jmeter, master-slave, distributed-testing

Can Jmeter master be used as a load generator instance in distributed testing framework? Since we mention host IPs, will it work to mention localhost and generate load from master?

Thanks,
Madhav

Comment: Start jmeter-server.bat/sh on load generator machine  with server address (which is its own ip/address). This way you will run two jmeter instances (one master, one slave) on master machine. One generating load and one controlling test and slaves.

Answer (score 0):

If you are launching from JMeter UI to start all instances - 127.0.0.1 (localhost) is available.

Both JMeter documentation pages are good source of information.
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html